# When must I switch to NavigationView and SwipeControl?

Tags: uwp

I've updated all nuget packages for our UWP app. It no longer compiles as HamburgerMenu and SlidableListItem have been deprecated. I'm trying to switch to NavigationView and SwipeControl. It is proving so difficult that I'm considering switching back to the older Nuget packages that still allowed HamburgerMenu.

Please can you tell me when I MUST switch to NavigationView? I suppose it's till I want to start using new features in updated Nuget packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please can you tell me when I MUST switch to NavigationView?

`NavigationView` is not a mandatory control, that need base on your app's architecture, NavigationView could make the app's navigate easily. And it has beautiful UI interface. So we recommend you use `NavigationView`. For `SwipeControl`, it's flexible control, you could custom the style and navigation(NavigationView is base on SwipeControl).

For using [`NavigationView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) in your app, you could check official document, and we also provide [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery).

**Update**

Windows Community Toolkit is open source, you could also separate `HamburgerMenu` from older version that could keep HamburgerMenu always could be used. And you could find could find HamburgerMenu [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/rel/3.0.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/HamburgerMenu/HamburgerMenu.cs).

Comment: The problem is that the HamburgerMenu has been deprecated! How long will I be able to still use it?

Comment: `HamburgerMenu` is  Windows Community Toolkit  control, and it is replaced with `NavigationView` control. you could still use it in uwp project. and it depend on Windows Community Toolkit nuget package version. If you used the following version does not contain's `HamburgerMenu`, the project will throw compile error.

Comment: So I could continue using HamburgerMenu for the next 5 years and not have any problems?

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft  Our uwp app is very complex. It is proving very difficult to switch to NavigationView (we use commands to navigate). My manager is asking is it worth the effort if eveything will be fine for another 5 years?

Comment: Windows Community Toolkit  is open source, you could also separate  HamburgerMenu from older version that could keep `HamburgerMenu` always could be used.

Comment: You can continue to use hamburger menu as long as your want. It *will* be removed from the Windows Community Toolkit Nuget package eventually, but you are free to include the source code directly in your project, which can be found on the official github repo for the project.

Comment: You could find `HamburgerMenu` from older [`version`](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/rel/3.0.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/HamburgerMenu/HamburgerMenu.cs).

Comment: hi @nico-zhu-msft, I copied the files for HamburgerMenu and SlideableListItem to my project and it's now running fine using the latest nuget packages! If you wish to edit your answer to give this option, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Can you give me any advice on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068607/cant-use-source-code-for-deprecated-control-slidablelistitem ? Really upset that what worked for the HamburgerMenu doesn't work for the SlidableListItem!