# Can't use source code for deprecated control SlidableListItem

Tags: uwp

Microsoft has deprecated SlidableListItem in favour of SwipeControl. I tried SwipeControl using the XAML controls gallery - it does not let me swipe left and right with a mouse (I can using SlidableListItem). I think I need a touchscreen device for it to work.

So I'd like to continue using SlidableListItem despite having updated to the latest nuget packages.

I've copied the code for SlidableListItem into my project from WindowsCommunityToolKit branch 4.0.0. I get this crash when I try to use the control:

> System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a
>   type.\r\n   at Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size
>   availableSize)

(I successfully copied the code for the HamburgerControl into my project yesterday.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to copy the source code of [SlidableListItem](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/rel/4.0.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/SlidableListItem), after paying attention to the following points, I successfully copied it:

1. If you don't need `SwipeControl`, please delete the related code:

   - Do not copy the code of `SlidableListItemSwipeControlTemplate.xaml`
   - Delete the properties and callback methods related to `UseSwipeControlWhenPossible` in **SlidableListItem.cs** (such as `OnUseSwipeControlWhenPossibleChanged`, `OnSwipeControlValueChanged`, `UpdateSwipeControlItems`, etc.)
   - In the `SledableListItem.cs` file, there are two places that refer to the resource file path, please modify it according to your own project structure (you can also delete the relevant code if `SwipeControl` is not needed)
2. If you are migrating the code to your own control library, please remember to introduce `SlidableListItem.xaml` resource file in **App.xaml**

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Controls/SlidableListItem.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

---

But in fact, `SwipeControl` is a common control that UWP adapts to the operating habits of different platforms. On the desktop, we hold down the left mouse button and drag and drop is usually used to perform the `transfer` operation instead of calling out the secondary menu (we usually right-click on the desktop).

Simulating touch screen operation experience in keyboard and mouse mode is sometimes not a pleasant thing. If you plan to adapt to the operation habits of multiple platforms, please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/collection-commanding) to add compound commands.

Comment: @richard-zhang-msft Please can you share your code? I'm struggling to get it working.

Comment: Hello, you can get the SlidableListItem code extracted here: [Github](https://github.com/Richasy/SlidableListItem-Demo)

Comment: @richard-zhang-msft  I copied your code into my project and it worked fine yesterday but today I'm getting the MeasureOverride error again. I'm going to remove SlidableListItem from my project and use a delete button.